# Different column width in 2 rows with bootstrap and custom post types

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a custom post type on my WP website and also using bootstrap.

I want to list 5 custom post type entries on my home page, and I want the first 3 to have class col-md-4 in one row and in the next row 2 cpt entries to have the class col-md-6

At the moment I have a class col-md-4 and 2 items in the 2nd row are not centered nicely.

This is my current code:

```
<div class="container-fluid gray-section">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php 
                        $projects = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'project','posts_per_page'=>5, 'order'=>'ASC'));
                        if ($projects) { ?>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <?php foreach ($projects as $post) { setup_postdata( $post ) ?>
                                <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-xxs-12 text-center ">
                                    <a class="highlights-item" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <div class="highlights-container">
                                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                                    <span class="highlights-title">
                                                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                    </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                                    <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                            </ul>
                                            <?php }
                                ?>  

                            </div> <!-- end row -->
                        </div> <!-- end container -->
                    </div> <!-- end container fluid -->
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of issue is usually solved by adding a count to foreach loop and adding 1 each time. Then within the loop you can check what the count is and apply specific classes. e.g.

```
<div class="container-fluid gray-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php 

            $projects = get_posts(
                array(
                    'post_type'=>'project',
                    'posts_per_page'=>5, 
                    'order'=>'ASC'
                )
            );

            if ($projects) { $count = 1; ?>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <?php foreach ($projects as $post) { 

                    setup_postdata( $post );
                    if( $count >= 4 ) { $extra_class = 'col-md-6'; }
                    else { $extra_class = 'col-md-4'; }

                    ?>
                            <li class="<?php echo $extra_class; ?> col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-xxs-12 text-center ">
                                <a class="highlights-item" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <div class="highlights-container">
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        <span class="highlights-title">
                                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php $count++; } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                        </ul>
                                        <?php }
                            ?>  

                        </div> <!-- end row -->
                    </div> <!-- end container -->
                </div> <!-- end container fluid -->
```

Give that a go...

Regards

Dan

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks for your time so far. Can you check your code as I think something is wrong with the variable "count" but as I'm not that good with php I cant figure out what. I see that my li do not have the right class  but it looks like this: <li class="1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-xxs-12 text-center ">  THANKS!

Comment: @pevoje ah sorry, accidentally echoed the $count variable when it should have been the $extra_class variable. I have made the correct amendment to my answer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
foreach ($projects as $post) { setup_postdata( $post ) 
?>
<li class="<?php echo ($i>2):'col-md-6'?'col-md-4' ?> col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-xxs-12 text-center ">
<a class="highlights-item" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
<div class="highlights-container">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<span class="highlights-title">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</span>
</div>
</a>
</li>
 <?php 
 $i++;
 } 
 wp_reset_postdata(); 
 ?>
```